# Linq: Is it possible to change a value of an array from a specific index?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this aray

```
string[] neworden = { "toggler-down", "toggler-down", "toggler-down", "toggler-down", "toggler-down" };
```

when I click in one of the five column of my table in the webform, I set a variable which indicate the column clicked.

For example : `var indexColumn = 3`

I would like to change to toggle-up in the column clicked

is it possible in Linq?

Comment: Linq is a "general set of language capabilities for querying and updating data"... it is not related to webforms in any special way. So your question makes no sense: is the same as asking if you can get it using foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do this with LINQ?

You can assign to a specific element of the array like this,

```
neworden[indexColumn] = neworden[indexColumn] == "toggler-down" ? 
        "toggler-up" : "toggler-down";
```

how would LINQ help?

---

Additionally,

Consider using `bool` to represent values that have two states.

Comment: thats true, I didn't know why I was thinking in that moment with Linq. Your response it is right

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to retrieve the column from the webform Table, then change the ordering and the columname. I don't know which framework you are using but this should be very possible. Look up which kind of table you are using for your framework (MVC, Umbraco?), then how to get columns from your Table object. The columns should have standard methods for mutating them.